# Show filtered list of links based on user profile?

Tags: 7, users, navigation

My end goal is to provide users access to digital files they have purchased. This is for a magazine, so there's 1 per month, with an archive going back for years.

I have been able to import user info via a CSV file, including columns correlating issue number with a 1 or 0. I can display this all in the user profile, but not in any useful way. I can't figure out how to generate custom links: "here it is" for 1 or "click here to buy" for 0. Or a file download. Or whatever.

A lot of modules seem to have something like this functionality, and I've tried a dozen now with scattered progress. Even just being told that one module (or a combination) would definitely work would assure me that my messing around was useful. I am also open to other approaches.

I have experience with PHP+MySQL—I could've coded this by hand pretty easily by now—but I am working for a non-profit. I hope to automate myself out of a job and leave them with something that won't require a programmer to maintain.

Comment: Can we hear more about how you implemented this? Is a digital file a content type with a File field?

Comment: Each issue has three digital files associated with it: mobi, pdf, and epub. I'm getting the idea that I should create a content type "Issue" which has all its associated details and files, and then a custom view where the user table filters which issues show up for them?

I'm mostly having trouble figuring out where to put what stuff in which layers, which I know isn't very helpful for asking the question. It's possible everything I need is already in core Drupal.